# Interactive beautiful slider line/ribbon plots of Pandas dataframe without putting data online (Maybe with IPython widgets?)

Tags: python, plot, ggplot2, widget, ipython

Consider the beautiful graph [code first, image not showing because I have no upvotes yet]:

```
import pandas as np
from plotnine import *

df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'Year': 2000, 'X':1, 'Y': 1, 'err': .1}, 
        {'Year': 2000, 'X':2, 'Y': 2, 'err': .2},
        {'Year': 2000, 'X':3, 'Y': 3, 'err': .3},
        {'Year': 2001, 'X':1, 'Y': 1, 'err': .1},
        {'Year': 2001, 'X':2, 'Y': 4, 'err': .3},
        {'Year': 2001, 'X':3, 'Y': 9, 'err': .5},
        {'Year': 2002, 'X':1, 'Y': 1, 'err': .2},
        {'Year': 2002, 'X':2, 'Y': 8, 'err': .6},
        {'Year': 2002, 'X':3, 'Y': 27, 'err': .9},
    ])
df.set_index('Year')
df['ymin'] = df['Y'] - df['err']
df['ymax'] = df['Y'] + df['err']


(ggplot(df, aes(x='X', y='Y', group='Year', color='Year', ymin='ymin', ymax='ymax'))
+ geom_line()
+ geom_ribbon(alpha=.2)
)
```

[Beautiful graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xapa2.png)

How can I make an interactive version of this plot where one can use a slider to change the year being graphed? In my real data set I have 20 years of data and I would like to see how the distribution of this line, and its error bar, changes over time simply by sliding from 1997-2017. **Importantly, I cannot upload the data to a server,** so that rules out Plotly.

I spent several hours trying to make this work with Bokeh, but could not figure out how to make it play nice with Pandas dataframes. This seems like something that should be easy to do! And yet so many of the tutorials seem incredibly dense and hard to follow.

Is it?

Edit: Can this be done with IPython widgets?

Answer (score 0):

check this code. Save it as 'script.py' and run it with `bokeh serve --show script.py`

It may not be the most simple way of doing it. I usually use the low-mid level api of bokeh to make my plots.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar, Slider, Button
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, widgetbox

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'Year': 2000, 'X':1, 'Y': 1, 'err': .1}, 
        {'Year': 2000, 'X':2, 'Y': 2, 'err': .2},
        {'Year': 2000, 'X':3, 'Y': 3, 'err': .3},
        {'Year': 2001, 'X':1, 'Y': 1, 'err': .1},
        {'Year': 2001, 'X':2, 'Y': 4, 'err': .3},
        {'Year': 2001, 'X':3, 'Y': 9, 'err': .5},
        {'Year': 2002, 'X':1, 'Y': 1, 'err': .2},
        {'Year': 2002, 'X':2, 'Y': 8, 'err': .6},
        {'Year': 2002, 'X':3, 'Y': 27, 'err': .9},
    ])
grouped = df.groupby('Year')

max_year = max(df['Year'])
min_year = min(df['Year'])

def ID_map(year,mini=min_year,maxi=max_year,palette=Viridis256):
    return int(round((year-mini)*(len(palette)-1)/(maxi-mini),1))

mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=Viridis256, low=min(df['Year']), high=max(df['Year'])) # linearly map the "Viridis256" list to the [low,high] range
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper,location=(0,0),label_standoff=15,title='Year') # define the color bar with the linear color mapper

fig = figure(name='fig')
fig.xaxis.axis_label = 'X'
fig.yaxis.axis_label = 'Y'

for year, group in grouped:

    colo = Viridis256[ID_map(year)]
    y_lower = group['Y'] - group['err']
    y_upper = group['Y'] + group['err']

    y_band = np.append(y_lower,y_upper[::-1])
    x_band = np.append(group['X'],group['X'][::-1])

    fig.line(x='X',y='Y',color=colo,source=ColumnDataSource(group),name=str(year))
    fig.patch(x_band,y_band,color=colo,line_alpha=1,fill_alpha=0.2,name=str(year)+' band')

fig.add_layout(color_bar,'right')

def update(attr,old,new):
    fig = curdoc().select_one({"name":"fig"})

    for rend in fig.renderers:
        try:
            rend.data_source
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            if str(new) in rend.name:
                rend.visible = True
            else:
                rend.visible = False

slider = Slider(start=min_year,end=max_year,step=1,title='Year',value=min_year,width=200)
slider.on_change('value',update)

def show_all():
    fig = curdoc().select_one({"name":"fig"})

    for rend in fig.renderers:
        try:
            rend.data_source
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            rend.visible = True

button = Button(label='Show all')
button.on_click(show_all)

grid = gridplot([[fig,widgetbox(slider,button)]],toolbar_location='left')

curdoc().add_root(grid)
```

I couldn't remember how to use the mapper directly to get the color while using fig.line() so I just wrote a small function that should give the same colors as the mapper used for the color bar.

Comment: This did not produce a graph for me.

Comment: @JGLA I have bokeh 0.12.10 and this works fine in firefox and chrome and IE. How are you running this?